# IIS 7 Access to the path is denied when trying to generate report

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis-7

We are getting this error message upon trying to generate a report not accessing a file. We are using IIS 7.

XXX is located on a different server than the web server.

```
2014-10-24 11:04:13,287 [5] ERROR FOUNDATION [(null)] - Access to the path '\\XXX   \file2022.pdf' is denied.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\XXX\file.pdf' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32   rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.WriteStreamToFile(Stream stream, String filename)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportStreamToFile(Stream stream, DiskFileDestinationOptions options)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)
   at GlobalFunctions.GenerateCrystalReport(String reportFileName, String outputFileName, List`1 params) in C:\NetProjects\branches\R7\GUIs\Foundation\App_Code\GlobalFunctions.vb:line 347
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must access files like this make sure your Application Pool is running as a domain user with read permission to that location.

Comment: The Identity is Network Service, what would I grant the read permission to?

Comment: Set a custom account instead, then grant permissions to that